# While trying to reverse a url in django template html file, exception 'NoReverseMatch' occurs. I included the additional parameter in views function

Tags: html, django, url, django-views, django-templates

```
def entry(request, name):
    content = util.get_entry(name.strip())
    if content == None:
        content = "## Page was not found"
    content = markdown(content)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {'content': content, 'title': name})

def edit(request,title):
    content = util.get_entry(title.strip())
    if content == None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {'error': "404 Not Found"})
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST.get("content").strip()
        if content == "":
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {"message": "Can't save with empty field.", "title": title, "content": content})
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return redirect("entry", name=title)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {'content': content, 'title': title})
```

> util has files that help get names of entered files, save a new entry or get content of entry.

```
{% extends 'encyclopedia/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}
   {{title}}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<a href="{% url 'edit' title %}" class="badge badge-info">Edit This Page</a>
    {{entry | safe }}
{% endblock %}
```

> layout has the standard block code of HTML

**edit.html** contains HTML code that gives a button on each page so that we can edit the content of the page entry and passes name='content' for the content to be edited.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:name>", views.entry, name = 'entry'),
    path("search", views.search, name= 'search'),
    path("newpage",views.create,name='create'),
    path("random",views.random,name='random'),
    path("edit", views.edit, name='edit')
]
```

> ***THIS IS A CS50w project and I have taken references from other sources.***

Comment: The path "edit" has no parameter title but you use it with a parameter in the href. You should post the complete error message to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing variable to the url while it doesn't really need any
Just add title parameter to edit path

`path("edit/<str:title>/", views.edit, name='edit')`

when passing an argument to django view, you have to set it in the url
`<type:argument_name>`
and in the view arguments
`def viewname(request, variable1, variable2...): pass`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).